# When a Nuget package is added, where are the stuff added located?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

In Visual Studio 2019 I added a Nuget package, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` version 3.14. The only visible change I can find is an extra line in `<ItemGroup>` in the .csproj file.

Where is the code of the package located?

How is version control impacted if my project is checked into TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages are in your build folder ie. `bin/debug` or `bin/release`

NuGet packages are typically omitted from source control repositories and  are restored with project dependencies before a build.

[Omitting NuGet packages in source control systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control)

Answer (score 1):

Nugets are saved under :

- `{project-root}\bin\{debug-release}\{target-framework}`
- `{project-root}\obj\{debug-release}\{target-framework}`

Additionally all nugets are cashed under below folder for future use :

- `%UserProfile%/.nuget/packages`